# ImportError: cannot import name 'Log' from 'rosgraph_msgs.msg'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am running docker container with ros2 galactic and ros1 noetic, and whenever I try to run the launch file the error appears saying

[image: image description]

The error have not appeared before and I don't know why this error appears suddenly.

I always source the ROS1 noetic then ROS2 galactic while using ros1_bridge to communicate with other container whose version is ROS1 melodic.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413530/importerror:-cannot-import-name-%27log%27-from-%27rosgraph_msgs.msg%27/) by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2023-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-03-18**:
In the future, please do not use screenshots of text. Instead, copy/paste the text into your description, and format it with the 101010 button. Thank you.

**Comment by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on 2023-03-21**:
@Mike Scheutzow Thank you for let me know! I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find the answer. As described in the error message, ROS2 does not use rospy and should replace it to rclpy.

---

Originally posted by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) with karma: 21 on 2023-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0